# FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP not working with startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Is there a way to prevent multiple instances of an activity from being created with `startActivityForResult`?

For example:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
            startActivityForResult(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
            }, 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Clicking on the button multiple times opens multiple instances of the `MainActivity` even though I've set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`

Edit: Looks like there's a difference in behaviour depending on what Android version I'm running on. Android 8 opens a new Activity but Android 13 does not open a new Activity. How do I ensure that all android versions have the Android 13 behaviour?

Comment: You are opening MainActivity from MainActivity. Is that the correct code?

Comment: Why are you opening the same `Activity`? That makes no sense.

Comment: Also, generally, to solve this problem you need to add code that prevents launching the `Activity` multiple times upon multiple button clicks. This is a general Android problem (that users can click buttons quickly multiple times) that you need to solve yourself.

Comment: @DavidWasser It's just an example to show that it's not working as expected

Comment: This is an edge case where the behaviour was changed at some point between Android 8 and Android 13. What would you expect to happen when you launch `ActivityX` from an instance of `ActivityX`. Personally I don't ever see the point of doing this if you don't expect a new instance to be created. In general, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` consistently works as expected on all Android versions, if you are launching a different `Activity`.

Comment: I'd expect it to do nothing if ActivityX is already at the top of the stack. And if it's not at the top, then I'd expect it to get moved to the top. That's what the documentation says it does.... What it should not do is create a new instance -- that's what the documentation says it doesn't do

Answer (score 0):

you can add  android:launchMode="singleTop" in the manifest of your activity.

```
android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
android:exported="false"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

Comment: This produces the same result